# How to remove spray paint smell from electronic device?

Tags: paint, electronics

I recently painted an electronic device with spray paint. I want to remove the smell. I cannot soak/wet my electronic device. Using liquid type solution may short-circuit my electronic device.

How can I remove the spray paint smell from my electronic device?

Comment: Welcome! I am going to close this as a duplicate of an existing question — while it's about removing the smell of paint _from a room_, it looks like the solutions suggested there would also work for your smaller item (and none involve soaking or washing). Please [edit] if you think it won't work, or if you give the suggested fix a shot and it doesn't work!